# UITableViewCell selectedBackgroundView does not work

Tags: ios, uitableview

My UITableViewCells are all pre-defined "Subtitle" style. I want to set the background image for a selected cell to another picture. I tried every which way to implement this and all methods discussed on stackoverflow seem to fail.
I tried again for some other, easier way to change the selectedBackgroundView property, like:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds] ;
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

But it doesn't work as well. What's wrong with that ?

Answer (score 18):

As I understand you want to set selected background image to your cell?

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]];
```

### **EDIT:**

As i know `UITableViewCell` can not be highlighted after selection in such common cases:

1. There is somewhere set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`
2. You implemented `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and it returns `nil`;
3. There is set `[self.tableView setAllowsSelection:NO];`
4. May be you set `self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`;  or `cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO`;
5. You subclassed UITableViewCell and implemented such methods not correct `setSelected:animated:` or `setHighlighted:animated`

May be share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code to investigate the problem

Comment: I tried this:
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imagedNamed:@"tab.png"]];
  cell.selectedBackgroundView = imageView;
But it doesn't work ... I select one of the cell in the tableview and nothing happens...

Comment: Your question not sounds clear. I still do not understand the problem exactly. As i understand your tableViewCell is not highlighted after selection, yes? I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you George. I set cell.selectionStyle to some other thing instead of UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the highlight color in several ways.

Change the `selectionStyle` property of your cell. If you change it to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`, it will be gray.

you can also check that property in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
//do something like this for color
cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

// for image
cell.selectedBackgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
```

Change the `selectedBackgroundView` property. Actually what creates the blue gradient is a view. You can create a view and draw what ever you like, and use the view as the background of your table view cells.

best of luck..

Comment: your first `cell.selectedBackgroundView` should be `cell.selectionStyle`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem appeared after compiling on Xcode 13 - sdk iOS 15+
with any change to the code. Eventually I subclassed the cell and add the code:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{   
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    
    [self.contentView insertSubview:self.selectedBackgroundView
    atIndex:0];
    
    self.selectedBackgroundView.hidden = !selected;
}
```